# python manage.py runserver - Error: no module named registration

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to run python manage.py runserver to start the development server and I receive the following error:

```
Error: no module named registration
```

In my common.py file I have under installed apps "registration".

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'rosetta',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'templatetag_handlebars',
'registration',
'appName.common',
'appName.users',
'appName.core',
```

)

I think this may be the culprit, but cannot be sure.

Can anyone tell me what I have done and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: The reason it is giving you that is error because it is looking at your installed apps and is expecting to find the registration module, but it cannot find it. Check that the recommendations app is in your site-packages. It should be in the same folder where you have django installed

Comment: add the path to your module in your settings

Comment: is the `registration` yours or a 3rd party app ?

Comment: hey barrigaj,

I cannot find the registration app in the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django folder.

If this app has gone/been deleted, should I try to re-install the project? Will that then fix the error?

Comment: *If this app has gone/been deleted, should I try to re-install the project?* > you tell us, it's your application, you should know why that app is there in the first place o-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `python shell` and do this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/your_registration_package_path')
```

Comment: I ran this command and it fixed my issue: easy_install -Z django-registration

Comment: Yeah, `django-registration` module wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

you might forgot add `registration` package to your `python sys path`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/your_path')
```

Comment: I am new to django & python, which page should I add this too?